# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'

Tags: sql, querying

Not sure how to fix this error

> Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'

Code:

```
SELECT 
    id, user_id, client_name, client_phone, 
    (SELECT name
     FROM users_permissions
     WHERE users_permissions.user_id = contracts.assistant_id) AS Consultant
FROM 
    contracts
WHERE 
    contracts_statuses IN (1, 2) 
    AND transaction_type = 'rent'
    AND DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m') > '2017-08'
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the date column to `date_format`, like `DATE_FORMAT(contracts.date, '%Y-%m')`

Answer (score 1):

The DATE_FORMAT() function formats a date as specified by a format mask.

syntax : `DATE_FORMAT(date, format_mask)`

so in this case you specifiy the date which needs to be masked with the required format. i.e :'%Y-%m'